# simulate for onClick not working in enzyme

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

This is a cancel button

```
<div className="cancelFileBtn" onClick={this.props.cancelFileSending}>
```

I need to simulate its click,I tried the following test

```
wrapper.find('.cancelFileBtn').simulate('click');
```

But the click function is still undefined...Did I miss anything else? 
and it will be very helpful if anyone can mention any changes if exist in simulating

```
<SendMessageButton onClick={this.props.handleClickSendMessage} loadingFile={this.props.loadingFile}/>
```

Comment: enzyme code looks fine. What do you mean exactly click function is undefined?

Comment: I am unable to find the change simulated by the function and when I tried to print the wrapper I could find there `onClick=[undefined]`

Comment: It seems like the function bound to `onClick` is undefined. Which wrapper are you talking about? `SendMessageButton` or `div.cancelFileBtn`? I would check if `this.prop.handleClickSendMessage` or `this. props.cancelFileSending` defined. Can you paste the full component code on here or gist?

Comment: I think I need the help in using find,my find doesn't work

Answer (score 15):

Can't tell much without seeing more codes, hope this helps:

```
const wrapper = mount(<Component />);
const cancelBtn = wrapper.find('.cancelFileBtn');

// Test that the button is truthy
expect(cancelBtn).to.have.length(1);

// Simulation
cancelBtn.simulate('click');
// or
cancelBtn.props().onClick();

// Test the output
expect(...).to.equal(...);
```

Comment: in my case works only cancelBtn.props().onClick(); simulate doesn't work

Comment: @AlexBelke you should use `cancelBtn.props().onPress();`

Answer (score 3):

Add `hostNodes()` and it should work I assume.

```js
wrapper.find('.cancelFileBtn').hostNodes().simulate('click');
```

should fix it